# "Did you bring a horse for me?" or "Have you brought…?"

Tags: american-english, present-perfect, past-simple

> Harmonica: Where's Frank?
>
> Snakey: Frank sent us.
>
> Harmonica: **Did you bring** a horse for me?
>
> Snakey (snickers): Well... looks like we're...
>   Sankey:  ... looks like we're shy one horse.
>
> Harmonica (shaking his head): **You brought** two too many.

This is a famous dialogue from the opening scene of Sergio Leone's *Once Upon a Time in the West* ([link](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0064116/quotes)).

I tend to use the Present Perfect in the emphasized sentences. Harmonica still refers to the present, doesn't he?

Answer (score 2):

The past simple is perfectly natural in American English, which does not have the British English preference for the present perfect for recent past events.

Even in British English, the past simple would be acceptable here. Harmonica, seeing only three horses, is asking about the past-time bringing of the horse, not the present-time situation of it having been bought.